# What does MM_* means for ASP Classic

Tags: asp-classic

I am looking through a legacy code base and many variables have the `MM_*` prefix.  What is the significance of that naming convention?

Comment: Means it was built using the Dreamweaver as the IDE. It isn’t great and used to make some awful code, feel for you.

Answer (score 4):

It has no significance other than it was used as an auto code generation style in the [Macromedia Dreamweaver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Dreamweaver) IDE *(later acquired by Adobe in 2005)*. Come across a few codebases like this myself and in some cases have had to refactor them from scratch due to how poor the auto generated code was.

If I was to guess the `MM` probably referred to MacroMedia.

Comment: Yeah, I used to be regular on forums where people arrived every day with this crappy code. I came to the point of telling them to just throw away that software and write the code themselves...